# Python Nmap module not found despite already being installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, nmap

I am trying to write a port scanning program as part of my course assignment. However, even after downloading Nmap, an error appeared. It says 'nmap' is not accessed by pylance. I cannot access it interactive mode either. I am still very new to programming so any form of help will be much appreciated
[As you can see here Nmap is already downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxdaq.png).
[But...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgwZQ.png)
[And...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrS2m.png)

I tried deleting and re-installing Nmap, that did not work. I searched YouTube for solutions, but a lot of the files and programs they had I did not. I have already downloaded nmap from the website too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that happened because you have many interpreter and you installing in another interpreter to fix that you need to change the interpreter you can see the documentation in
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

or you can try using python venv by write this command in your terminal

```
python -m venv venv
```

after that activate the venv and activate the venv

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

after you activate the venv you just need to install the nmap

```
pip install python-nmap
```

I hope this answer can solve your problem

Comment: Hi, yes this did help with my problem. Thank you very much. May I also ask what is venv? What difference does it make

Comment: venv is a virtual environment that provides by python to make another python system in one computer. simply can install different versions of python on one computer without affecting another python. Usually, when we want to install another version of python we need to uninstall the older version and install the latest one but with env we can install the older one and latest one without uninstall the other one.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Learnt something new today

Answer (score 0):

You might have multiple version of python installed. When you run `py` is opens up `3.10.7` for you. You need to make sure you installed `python-nmap` for that version.

Apart from using a virtual environment, a quick fix would be to try installing nmap using `pip3`

`pip3 install python-nmap`

This will install nmap for your python3 installation. However if you have multiple python3 installations, I would suggest using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) of the particular python version you want.

Comment: I treid using pip3, but it did not work. How do I ensure I am only using version of python?

Comment: One option can be to do `which python` and see which installation is being used. Otherwise creating a virtual env might be a more noble choice.

Comment: I tried that but it said which is not recognised